# How can i calculate the contour integral of this trigonometric function?

Tags: contour-integration, complex-integration, trigonometric-integrals

Here's my integral $\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{cos(n\theta)}{cosha+acos\theta}d\theta$ where $|a|<1$

I tried $\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{e^{in\theta}}{cosha+acos\theta}d\theta$ but stuck here because of denominator.

Then i used $cos\theta=\frac{1}{2}(z+\frac{1}{z})=\frac{1}{2}(e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta})$ and $cos(n\theta)=\frac{1}{2}(e^{in\theta}+e^{-in\theta})$

So my integral turns into $\oint \frac{1/2(e^{in\theta}+e^{-in\theta})}{cosha+\frac{a}{2}(e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta})}\frac{dz}{iz}$
But nothing useful comes from here since $cosh (a)$ is so restrictive.

How can I calculate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINTS.

First of all rewrite the integral in a more "pleasing" way:

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\cos(n\theta)}{A + B\cos(\theta)}\ \text{d}\theta$$

Where of course $A = \cosh(a)$, $B = a$.

Then apply the Complex Step as you "almost" did:

$$z = e^{i\theta} ~~~~~~~~~~~\text{d}\theta = \frac{\text{d}z}{iz} ~~~~~~~~~~~ \cos(\theta) = \frac{1}{2}\left(z^2 + 1\over z\right) ~~~~~~~~~~~ \cos(n\theta) = \Re\left(z^n\right)$$

This leads to

$$-2i\int_{|z| = 1} \frac{\Re(z^n)\ \text{d}z}{ z^2 + bz + 1}$$

Where $b = B/A$.

Now it's all about to understand what $b^2 - 4$ is to get the hypothetical poles.

Poles are at

$$z_{1,\ 2} = \frac{-b \pm\sqrt{b^2-4}}{2}$$

It's not easy to determine which one lies inside the unit circle due to the unknown parameter $a$, but suppose we "know" that only

$$z = \frac{-b + \sqrt{b^2-4}}{2}$$

lies inside the unit circle (remember that $b = B/A = \cosh(a)/a$, so it would be immediate with numbers).

Then by residues theorem we have

$$\text{Integral} = -2i\left(2\pi i \times \sum_k \text{Residues}[f(z), z_k]\right)$$

In our case

$$f(z) = \frac{\Re(z^n)}{\left(z - \frac{-b + \sqrt{b^2-4}}{2}\right)\left(z - \frac{-b-\sqrt{b^2-4}}{2}\right)}$$

Whence

$$\text{Residue} = \lim_\left\{z\to \frac{-b + \sqrt{b^2-4}}{2}\right\} \ \frac{-b + \sqrt{b^2-4}}{2}\cdot f(z) = \dfrac{(\sqrt{b^2-4}-b)^n}{2^n \sqrt{b^2-4}}$$

And finally:

$$\text{Integral} = -2i\left(2\pi i \times \text{Res}\right) = 4\pi \dfrac{(\sqrt{b^2-4}-b)^n}{2^n \sqrt{b^2-4}}$$

Where again $b = \left(\dfrac{\cosh(a)}{a}\right)^{-1}$

Comment: Thanks a lot. It looks very useful. I just want to ask about last part. You suppose to find poles of z with $\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$, right? Then of course I use those poles to find residues

Comment: @KonstantinNovoselov I added something to the answer!

Comment: Okay it's now totally clear. I tried to get rid of that cosha which is useless attempt as I can see now. Thank you very much!

Comment: @KonstantinNovoselov You're welcome, I am going to check it again and again, hoping I did not write some malarkey :D

Comment: the only wrong part is last $b=cosh(a)/a$. Because at the beginning it was $b=B/A=a/cosh(a)$

Comment: @KonstantinNovoselov Uh, thank you so much. I am about to edit ( I was answering to another question of yours :D )

Comment: well, okay. thanks :D